# Synchronization with .NET webservice

Tags: .net, sql-server, json, web-services, web

we are developing application for mobile units (vhecicles). This units will have it's own data sources and it's own .NET web service (JSON). In application we will be showing data for own and other untis (with webservice).

The problem arises when some of mobile unit goes offline and gets back online. Is there any solution for synchronizing data with .NET webservice or something like that. Or maybe database synchronization?

Do you have any suggestions?

Maybe we need central server for saving data form all mobile uints?!

Thank you.

Comment: A central service won't help you: if the device is offline then how can it connect to the central service? You need to save data locally and then synchronise. If you have any data which can be updated by multiple elements of the distributed system then you have to resolve the conflict (and that, of course, if the hard part).

Comment: You can create something called version of business objects, when somebody edit your object increase its version and when service comes up just check if your device and server are using same version or not, its lie check sum.